# Is it a good practise to hold an Object Store in custom Application class

Tags: java, android, performance

I want to use an object in many places in my app: Fragments, Activities, even in services.

Is there a better way to do this than how I have done it below?

I also want to know if there are any other good practices.

Is it better to make the object static or not static?

Does the Application class always hold the object when I call it from any activity or background services?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private static DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper dao;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      dao = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this,
            getString(R.string.db_name), null);
   }

   public static DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper getDao() {
      return dao;
   }

   public static void setDao(DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper dao) {
      MyApplication.dao = dao;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like static fields and methods. I think it's wrong for OOP paradigm. You can facing with a lot of problem with multithreading access to your database.

In your case you can hold object as non-static field and access it from activity or service  like this:

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDao()
```

For case like yours, you can use Dependency Injection. There is good lib for that on android (Dagger by squareUp). With it, you can easily "inject" you object in many places.

Comment: ok thanks for you help 
I really didn't understand Dependency Injection

Comment: ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDao() 
does it make problem when i call it from service stared form Alarm services or any other place other than Activity

Comment: @saleeh93 I suggest you to try. But be carefull, because dagger is good for android, but RoboJuice not. It's bad idea to use DI library, which are using reflection. Dagger is compile time DI, not runtime.

Comment: @saleeh93 it must work in service and activity. In other places, you must access activity object and then access application throw activity object. DI will solve this problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your comment about not using static field or methods in a oo language is an opinion rather than an agreed upon standard. There are many reasons to disassociate a method from an instance. What if you were using the singletons pattern, and needed a factory? Wouldn't you keep the implementation together and have a static method to create an instance? And a static property to store this instance? Just one example.

Comment: @FabianCook Sure, it's my opinion and I write, that "I don't like". And I'm using static methods for singletons, builders and factory. Therefore I don't like to have data detached from instance. I prefer to avoid using static fields in case like this, because I can't get full controll about lifecycle of static field and can't garantee thread safe operating with it.

Comment: So it's static fields you are against? Don't disregard the entire concept because one part doesn't work for you.

Comment: @FabianCook I don't say, that smth not working for me. It's my own opinion about static fields. I think it's not practice discussion, but ideology discussion. Author ask for better way, I suggest the way, which I prefer. I think there are a lot of patterns that somebody likes and don't likes.